# Check if string value changes

Tags: java, string, variables, compare, runtime

I have a code which is getting the current memory use of the explorer.exe, using the runtime exec and then calling a command. Then I use that whole line and turn it into a string variable, I would now like to be able to check if this string changes. This is to check whether the memory part, which is a number, changes over time. The whole purpose is to see whether the explorer is being used or not. As long as the memory use isn't changing the explorer isn't in use, but if it does, it means it is in use.

The usual output from the command would be `explorer.exe 776 console 1 35,804K` and then the last part `35,804K` is the memory output, which is the part I would like to monitor or keep track of.

The code I currently have, is the one seen below. Initially I would also implement a Timer, to make it run all the time.

```
public class ReadProcser {

    static String runTVal = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        functionReadRegular();
        } finally {
        if (runTVal != runTVal)
        {
        System.out.println("Changed");
        }
        }
    }

    static void functionReadRegular(){
        try {
            String process;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c tasklist /FI \"IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe\"");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((process = input.readLine()) != null) {
                runTVal = process;
                System.out.println(runTVal);
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I am aware that the current way of checking whether the string is changing doesn't work. It is more to show what I am trying to do, currently it doesn't have a value from the start and thus doesn't have anything to compare with. But it is more to show what I am trying to achieve. I have seen something about having a certain `Listener` which checks whether the string has changed, but I am not sure how to actually use it in a case like this.

If it isn't visible enough through the code, it is basically the String `runTVal` I would like to first get, then save it and then run the code again to get a new value as `runTVal` and then compare the old with the new.

Comment: While your premise may work in general, how do you plan to handle edge cases where the Explorer memory usage, for some reason, does not change although it is still in use?

Comment: Strings are immutable, also learn how to compare Strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understood it, you are looking to compare to output of that CMD command in a loop, checking the results over time.

Below, I modified your code to read the value of the command, wait 500 milliseconds, and compare the previous value with the new one. Any of the fields could have changed, not just the memory. However, I think this may be a step in the direction of what you are trying to do.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReadProcser {

    private static final int TIME_WAIT = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            String val = getRunTVal();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(TIME_WAIT);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!val.equals(getRunTVal())) {
                System.out.println("Changed");
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getRunTVal() {
        String runTVal = null;
        try {
            String process;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c tasklist /FI \"IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe\"");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((process = input.readLine()) != null) {
                runTVal = process;
                System.out.println(runTVal);
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        return runTVal;
    }

}
```

As Tim Biegeleisen mentioned, there are cases when this may not be reliable. For example, if any field other than the memory changed in the output (such as the session # or amount of whitespace), the message "Changed" would still be printed to the console, even though the memory stayed the same.

Did I help at all, or did I miss your point?

Comment: seems a bit strange to call `getRunTVal` twice within the loop

Comment: Wouldn't that be necessary, though? You need to compare before and after the thread sleeps, so you need to call it before and after. Maybe there is a way to optimize it, though.

Comment: I would have put `one call` before the loop and then `one call` in the loop. Also I would have updated `val` if it changes

Comment: @steveg I really appreciate the input, it basically does work for my case. The only thing which might have been an improvement, would be to check whether that last number every time has increased or decreased, to make sure it only triggers if the memory increased. Although that doesn't seem to be possible for strings.

Answer (score -3):

Strings are Objects so when you call == or != they compare the value stored there. Integers for example would hold their number, but objects compare a reference that says where their data is stored. So even if both strings are the same thing word, they will not be equal since they are stored at different locations. To compare what they store use .equals like if(stringA.equals(stringB)).